# Defining keyboard shortcuts involving the Fn key

Tags: linux, ubuntu, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I am accustomed to pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> to simulate the <kbd>Home</kbd> key and <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> for <kbd>End</kbd>.

On a keyboard with physical <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> keys, using these <kbd>Fn</kbd> keyboard shortcuts do not work.

How can I map custom <kbd>Fn</kbd> keyboard shortcuts on **Ubuntu** Linux?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bind multimedia keys](http://superuser.com/questions/425725/bind-multimedia-keys). It is not an exact duplicate in the problem description perhaps, but it is solved by the same underlying process.

Comment: Is anybody using modern (2018) laptops like HP Spectre x360 (although it has separate PgUp etc keys )  and Dell XPS aware if the Function key is detected like the other keys are?

Comment: I am using Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Carbon with `Fn` key, which is detected as keycode 151 by `xev`. While `Fn` is pressed `Left` and `Right` keys produce no events. `Fn+F2` produces no events, but works as expected - lowers volume.

Answer (score 26):

Unlike modifiers such as Alt and Ctrl, pressing the Fn key is never communicated to the operating system. The key merely modifies the scancodes of other keys, so pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> would emulate an End key, even though it may not physically exist, but they are indistinguishable by the OS. This behaviour is controlled exclusively by the keyboard electronics and can therefore not be altered without messing with the circuitry or microcontroller.

Comment: There is one operating system and computer that is definitely an exception to this rule and that is mac laptops.  You can modify this key using Karabiner  actually.  Also thinkpads send this key to the operating system but it isn't a modifier key like on macs.

Comment: This is not true. `xev` shows `Fn` key presses.

Comment: Well, on my Dell machine with a Debian 10, `xev` doesn't show anything when Fn key is pressed.

Comment: @Suor Which system was that? We all want one!

Comment: @joeytwiddle it's Ubuntu 20.10 on Thinkpad X1 Carbon

Comment: A DasKeyboard connected to mac doesnt (at least by default) send its fn key whereas a Nuphy Air75 does

Answer (score 17):

On most systems it is not possible to detect the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key itself, but you could try using:

```
$ xev | grep --line-buffered keysym
```

to find out what keys <kbd>Fn-Left</kbd> and <kbd>Fn-Right</kbd> do send.  (The `grep` just reduces the noise.)

If you are lucky, those keypresses will send unimportant keystrokes to the machine, which you can then remap.

For example, on my system, `xev` shows that my <kbd>Fn-Left</kbd> keypress actually sends an `XF86AudioPrev` event:

```
state 0x0, keycode 173 (keysym 0x1008ff16, XF86AudioPrev), same_screen YES,
```

I can easily remap this to translate into a <kbd>Home</kbd> key event:

```
$ xmodmap -e 'keysym XF86AudioPrev = Home'
```

Hopefully you will be able to do the same for End, PageUp and PageDown.

Unfortunately if xev does not receive anything unique when you press <kbd>Fn-Left</kbd> then you are out of luck.

It's a real shame that <kbd>Fn</kbd> keypresses are not sent directly like the other modifier keys are.  If they were, we would have much more power to configure their meaning through software.

Comment: Unfortunately fn on my laptop doesn't register with key up and key down events in the same way as other keys there by keeping this from working correctly for a modifier key.  You can remap it to other one press keys though.

Answer (score 7):

I opened `xev` in a terminal. It detects when I press the <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, and <kbd>Win</kbd> (<kbd>Super</kbd>), but when I pressed the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key it doesn't detect it.

So the software has nothing to do with the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key; it's up to the hardware to decide what key gets sent to the software (e.g. the <kbd>Home</kbd> or <kbd>End</kbd> key).

So your keyboard must already have it to be able to do this.