# Defining keyboard shortcuts involving the Fn key on Windows

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

As asked in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/428945/defining-keyboard-shortcuts-involving-the-fn-key), I am used to pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> on my laptop's keyboard to simulate the <kbd>Home</kbd> key and <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> for <kbd>End</kbd>.

However, I have a wireless keyboard with physical <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> keys, and using these keyboard shortcuts <kbd>Fn</kbd> does not work on it.

Is it possible to assign custom <kbd>Fn</kbd> keyboard shortcuts in Windows? I would also like to change, if possible, some of the other shortcuts on my wireless keyboard that involve the Fn key, so that this keyboard is set up the same way as the laptop's built-in keyboard.

Comment: there's no way to remap the `Fn` key on a PC: [How do you disable the Fn key on a keyboard in Windows?](https://superuser.com/q/1434881/241386), [Assign Home and End to Fn+arrows](https://superuser.com/q/1069211/241386), [Is it possible to create your own Fn+Key combinations on Windows 8.1?](https://superuser.com/q/928299/241386), [Remap FN to another key](https://superuser.com/q/65/241386)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remap FN to another key](https://superuser.com/questions/65/remap-fn-to-another-key)

Comment: Keys cost money. The reason you have to press Ctrl+Alt+Delete to logon is because an IBM engineer in charge of keyboards refused Microsoft's request for a logon key on cost grounds. Laptop manufacturers use the `Fn` key to typically (as all are different) map App keys to Function keys. On my computer - I press F11 and IE will go full screen because the keyboard send the F11 key to Windows. I press `Fn+F11` it send the app key volume up. Fn and power keys are not part of the keyboard. There are three types of keys that relate to newer keyboards.

Comment: They are equivalent to each other only and are distinguished from when there were introduced. 84 key keyboards (page up etc are on the numeric keypad), 101 key keyboards (dedicated page up/insert keys), and app keys (volume etc).

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite certain I fully understand what you want to do, but, in short, I would suspect you're likely out of luck regarding anything having to with <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys. Function keys are often hardware-based, rather than software-based, so it isn't necessarily possible to emulate them.